# No component factory found in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a component in src/component/accounting-setting

1. accounting-setting.ts
2. accounting-setting.html
3. accounting-setting.scss
4. accounting-setting.module.ts

Source code is

```
import { NgModule , ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AccountingSettingComponent } from './accounting-setting';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AccountingSettingComponent,
  ],

imports: [IonicModule], 
  entryComponents: [
       AccountingSettingComponent
  ],

exports: [AccountingSettingComponent]
})

export class AccountingSettingComponentModule {}
```

but when I add this component in other component in src/pages/accounting.module.ts

```
import { NgModule , ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AccountingPage } from './accounting';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'; 
import { AccountingSettingComponentModule } from '../../components/accounting-setting/accounting-setting.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [
    Chart,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AccountingPage),
    AccountingSettingComponentModule,


  ],
  entryComponents: [

  ],
})
export class AccountingPageModule {}
```

throw error no component factory found actually I use this for popover where popover html in account-setting.html. To prevent it from lazy loading I would not add this in app.module.ts

Answer (score 2):

**There are two scenarios this error may happen:**

1. You try to navigate [navCtrl.push(...)] to a Page.
2. You try to navigate to a component.

**The proper way to do it, when using lazy loading:**

1. Create a module with compatible name to the page.
2. Add the page / component to the module, into the sections: declaration, exports, entryComponents.
3. If you navigate to a component, you need to add the *module* to the app.module.ts import section.
4. Navigate to a page with the proper syntax:

**4.1 page (Page name as string '' ):**

```
this.navCtrl.push('ExamplePage', {})
```

**4.2 component (Component class - not as a string):**

```
this.navCtrl.push(ExamplePageComponent, {})
```

**Navigate to a Page / Component with lazy loading:**

**example.page.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      ExamplePage,
      ExampleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ExamplePage),
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    IonicImageLoader,
  ],
  exports: [
      ExamplePage,
      ExampleComponent

  ],
  entryComponents: [
      ExamplePage,
      ExampleComponent
  ]
})
export class ExamplePageModule { }
```

**example.page.ts**

```
@IonicPage({
    name: 'ExamplePage'
})
@Component({
   selector: 'example-page',
   templateUrl: 'example.page.html'
})

export class ExamplePage {
    constructor() {};
}
```

**example.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example-component',
templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})

export class ExampleComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

**Add this only when navigating to a Component with lazy loading, adding the lazy load module, that have the component that will become entryComponent required in order to attach Factory to create it:**

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}),
    ExamplePageModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following from you `account-setting.module.ts`

```
entryComponents: [
       AccountingSettingComponent
  ]
```

**Why?**

> An entry component is any component that Angular loads imperatively by
>   type.
>
> A component loaded declaratively via its selector is not an entry
>   component.
>
> Most application components are loaded declaratively. Angular uses the
>   component's selector to locate the element in the template. It then
>   creates the HTML representation of the component and inserts it into
>   the DOM at the selected element. These aren't entry components.

You are loading the `account-setting` component declaratively and as an entry when you should only be declaring and exporting the component in the module file.

[Reference by Angular](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#q-entry-component-defined)

Comment: Thank you very much #Sam5487 very informative reference and your answer but still problem remain maybe  i am doing wrong. I am generating component for popover but i am doing like ionic page creation. I have to follow selector property and control all happening by Input , Output event. Am i right @Sam5486

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ViewChild in the angular module declaration. Also, you'll need IonicPageModule instead of IonicModule. Your declarations is fine. In your imports: `[IonicPageModule.forChild(AccountingSettingComponent)]`. You don't need entry Components here.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AccountingSettingComponent} from './accounting-setting';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AccountingSettingComponent],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(AccountingSettingComponent)], 
  exports: [AccountingSettingComponent]
})

export class AccountingSettingComponentModule {}
```

In your other module, follow a similar approach and decorate your component with IonicPage() before you serve it.

if your initial module was supposed to be a shared module then you do not need the scss, html and ts files for it.

an example of shared module

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core"
import {CheckboxComponent} from "./checkbox/checkbox";
import {IonicModule} from "ionic-angular";
import {DeviceCardComponent} from "./device-card/device-card";
import {TemplateCardComponent} from "./template-card/template-card";

@NgModule({
    declarations:
        [
            CheckboxComponent,
            DeviceCardComponent,
            TemplateCardComponent 
        ],
    imports: [IonicModule],
    exports:
        [
            CheckboxComponent,
            DeviceCardComponent,
            TemplateCardComponent
        ]
})
export class ComponentsModule{}
```

and add this shared module to the import of any other module where you are trying to use any of these components.

Comment: Thanx @Anjil Dhamala , actually issue is that i can prevent my app from lazy loading so i can't load my component in app.module.ts. I will follow your pattern but i am confused, when i import this module in my other custom component app will again throw error no component factory found.

Comment: And how i will be able to use popover component in my custom.ts file as   let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(ComponentsModule);  Is this true that i will use this

Comment: do you want lazy loading or not? I'm confused. If you do not want it, you can eagerly load all of your components in appmodule. If you want it, this is the way to go. To use a popover in any of your component, just inject the popover controller in that component's constructor and start using it. You don't have to worry about angular modules or ionic page modules if you just want to use popover. However, if you are trying to create a generic component with popover and use that component in other components, just add that component to declarations of page module and start using it.

Comment: Oh really such a good answer. I got your point. My app start working actually i am confused again thanx @Anjil Dhamala

Comment: let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: Thanx @Anjil Dhamala